# How to get JComboBox value as enum value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've created JComboBox like this:

```
mode = new JComboBox(SpawnMode.values());
```

SpawnMode enum looks like this:

```
public enum SpawnMode {
   POINT,
   RANDOM,
   INWARD_CIRCLE,
   RANDOM_CIRCLE
}
```

How do I get selected value from JComboBox as a enum value to assign it like below?

```
SpawnMode value = selected_value
```

Comment: Casting is required here because [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) predates the invention of [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). Swing’s modern replacement [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) does support Generics, so no casting needed with its [`ComboBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque technically, there is a way without casting - see my comment to the answer (it's the ItemSelectable that's not generified, JComboBox and its model are)

Answer (score 2):

Cast you're *selected_value* to the enum type.

```java
SpawnMode value = (SpawnMode) selected_value
```

In this case, use *[JComboBox#getSelectedItem](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem())*.

```java
SpawnMode value = (SpawnMode) mode.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: But what to replace the 'selected_value' with to get the value from JComboBox?

Comment: well. yes. combo isn't fully generified (astonishingly!) - nevertheless application code should use generic typing as far as possible (that is, type the combo with spawnMode) - which would allow to prevent the type-cast (by going via selectedIndex/valueAt). just saying :)

Comment: @kleopatra, can you provide an example?

Comment: hmm .. which part isn't clear? Just look at the api doc of JComboBox (and maybe also ComboBoxModel - don't have it handy right now) and apply what you see ..

Comment: @kleopatra, you're response.... It's why I asked if you could provide an example.

Comment: @kleopatra, you're saying, _"type the combo with spawnMode"_, can you provide an example of typing the combo with spawnMode?  Is this somehere in the JavaDoc?

Comment: hmmm .. just the same as always:`JComboBox<SpawnMode> combo = new JComboBox<>()`

Comment: @kleopatra, ok, excellent.  As a note, I believe the variable name was _mode_, and not _combo_.

Comment: @kleopatra, and to capture a value from _combo_, how would this be done?  Is there a JavaDoc spec you can refer us to?

Comment: @kleopatra, and as a final note, you mentioned that _"combo isn't fully generified"_.  What implications should we infer?  Will this create any notable draw backs or a loss of design congruence?

Comment: @kleopatra, well, of course.  I thought you were applying something; I figured an elaboration would help.  Should I add in something about referring to the documentation?  I'm not sure I completely understand your comments.  Try providing an answer.